# HTTP User Agent detection

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, user-agent

I'm in the middle of a research. I'm using Bootstrap for building a responsive website but the loading speed is actual quite slow. There is a lot of stuff I use for desktop which is not needed for mobile or tablet. I came across scrips like this: http://mobiledetect.net/ and was questioning the worth to install and use it. Do you have any experience using this kind of scripts and important question does it work like it says it works?

Can you tell me more about the advantages and disadvantages of using this kind of scripts?

Comment: what do u want to use the script for?

Comment: I want to strip script for example navigation on mobile since there are 2 navigation options on desktop and I don't want to use it on mobile.

Comment: css media queries are for that purpose. I suggest that u learn css media quiries

Comment: I already used them quite a lot but they are still in the source which makes loading time quite long.

Comment: or host your css and images using a cdn..  here's one : https://www.cloudflare.com/

Comment: I don't think it's my CSS which makes the site slow because all is optimized. I think it's due to source which is not used on mobile and only appears on desktop. All above is already done. So I wanted to know if someone has a good experience using these kind of PHP scripts.

Comment: what's ur website url?

Comment: Due to the privacy of the client I can't tell you that. Sorry

Comment: Then how do u expect to get help if we can't view the website?

Comment: I asked for the advantages and disadvantages of using these kind of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

in php it is easy to detect the device it works 99% of the time

```
<?php
$device = '1';
$info= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if( stristr($info,'ipad') ) || ( stristr($info'],'iphone') ) ||  (  stristr($info'],'blackberry') ) ||  ( stristr($info'],'android') ){ 
       $device = "0"; 
       } 
if($device=='0'){
//redirect to mobile site
       }
?>
```

i use this way to check and use it because my layout for mobile is a lot different then on computer. The advantage is you can make the site look better on mobile and computer. The disadvantage is you have to do double work lol.If you want to add more devices then you can echo the $info variable and find the unique string from device and add another or condition